# C++ reading numbers from txt until change of line (logistic regression)

Tags: c++, string, ifstream

I'm really bad in programming but want to do this one and I dont't want to stop trying.It's for my course A.I.
So, I have a txt file (train1.txt)that contains series of numbers like this:

```
0 0 0 12 14 55 250 0 0 1 14 44 5 4 0 0    
0 0 0 0 1 2 55 89 201 4   
0 45 78 98 65 2 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
.
.
.
```

It has around 6000 lines and 1700 numbers in each line. Every line is supposed to be an image of 28*28 pixels(I don't really understand this).
I need to do a Logistic Regression algorithm(categorize handwritten characters into ones and sevens) so I need to save these numbers in to an array/vector and do some calculations.
what i have done so far is this

```
int main() 
{
    ifstream file("train1.txt");
    string line;
    vector<int> train1 (20000);//if i don't give a size it won't work    
    if (file.is_open())
    {
    int i=0;
    int k=0;
    int tens,hundreds;
    if(getline(file,line))
    {
            while (line[i] !='\n')//i want to do this till the end of the line
            {
                if(line[i]==' ')//if it's a space just go to the next one
                {i++;}
                else //it has for sure 1 digit
                {
                    tens=0;
                    hundreds=0;
                    i++; //check the next one
                    if(line[i] !=' ') //does it have 2 digits?
                    {
                        i++; //check the next one
                        if (line[i] !=' ') //does it have 3 digits?
                        {   //3 digit number
                            cout<<line[i-2]<<line[i-1]<<line[i]<<endl;
                            hundreds = (line[i-2] - '0')*100;
                            tens =  (line[i-1] - '0')*10;
                            train1[k]=hundreds + tens + line[i]- '0';;
                            k++;
                            i++;
                        }
                        else//just 2digit number
                        {
                            cout<<line[i-1]<<line[i]<<endl;
                            tens = (line[i-1] - '0')*10;
                            train1[k]=tens +line[i]- '0';
                            k++;
                            i++;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {//just 1digit number
                        cout<<line[i-1]<<endl;
                        train1[k]=line[i-1] - '0';
                        k++;
                        i++;
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

**The thing is that i can't stop it when the line is changed. It works fine Ι think but in the end it says "string subscript out of range"**. That is because when I am in the last number of the line I still do i++ and try to access line[i], right?

Comment: You are reinventing the wheel! You should use the builtin functions of iostream to read numbers, e.g. `file >> someInteger;`

Comment: Try erasing the last character of the string when you read the line into it to begin with.  That will just remove the newline character and the rest of the string should be the info you want to parse.

Comment: @Kvothe I don't really understand what you say i should do.

Comment: @Shadocko how do i do that for every line ? I really understand now how much easier it might have been... :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can construct a stream from a string ("stringstream") and use that to read numbers from - it works like any other stream.

You'd wind up with something like this:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() 
{
    std::ifstream file("train1.txt");
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(file,line))
    {
        std::vector<int> numbers;
        std::stringstream linestream(line);
        int value = 0;
        while (linestream >> value)
        {
            numbers.push_back(value);
        }
        // Do something with the data from this line...
        do_something_with(numbers);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that and while I am trying to print the number vector to check if it's right , it prints nothing.

Comment: Yeah you are right it was my fault out of rush! Thaks a lot! I will keep going!